# File storage backend for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, storage

I have a Rails application that I want to add file upload to, so that the users have access to a "resources" section where they can upload and share (although not publicly) any type of file. I know I could build a solution using paperclip and S3 for example, but to try and avoid the admin overhead of all that I'm looking at API interfaces to drop.io and box.net. Does anyone have any experience of these? I've got a basic demo working rather well to drop.io, but I was just wondering if anyone had any better ideas or experiences.

Many thanks
D

Comment: Have you looked at attachment_fu (http://github.com/technoweenie/attachment_fu)?  It makes using S3 pretty painless.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific on what 'admin overhead' you're hoping to avoid with paperclip and S3?  In my experience, using both of those in tandem has been incredibly painless (with no admin overhead).

Comment: I hadn't looked at attachment_fu no, I'll have a look into it. The reason I think there's "admin overhead" is that the only project I've worked on where they used S3 was where no plugin was used and there seemed to be lots of manipulation of buckets and so on and it all seemed over complicated. I'll try it with one of the above gems and see how it goes. Many thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 1):

I use attachment_fu with S3 backend. For User Interface goodness, I use [YUI's file uploader](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/uploader/).

Some of the files are uploaded with world read access, others with no public read access.
I use Attachement_fu to create self-signed urls to enable clients to access the private S3 files.

I did write some small helper routines for the S3 library for re-connecting after a timeout, handling various errors that the S3 library can raise, etc.

**Building your own library for drop.io and/or box.net**

Your idea of using the API for a commercial service is interesting but I haven't run into any problems with the above config. And the price for direct S3 access is very low.

If you do decide to go this route, you may want to open source your code. You'd benefit by getting testing, ideas, and possible code contributions from the community.

Note that if you have a *lot* of uploads, you can end up with a performance issue if the uploads are synchronous with the Rails thread--the rails process is busy uploading and can't do anything else until the upload is done.

HTH,

Larry

Comment: Hi,

the YUI uploader sounds interesting, I didn't know about that (I do use YUI quite a lot so it shouldn't be too hard to get it working) - I'll give it a try. Interesting about the performance issue - in theory it shouldn't be a problem because the uploads will be once only. I'll bear it in mind though. Many thanks for your post!